# Overlaying two PDFs using PDFtk - stamp gets cropped

Tags: pdf, merge, overlay, ghostscript, pdftk

I have two PDFs from two different sources that are exactly the same size. I want to overlay one on top of the other.

Output from `pdfinfo -box -f 1 -l 3 top.pdf`:

```
Creator:        cairo 1.10.2 (http://cairographics.org)
Producer:       cairo 1.10.2 (http://cairographics.org)
Tagged:         no
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page    1 size: 419.2 x 594.4 pts
Page    1 MediaBox:     0.00     0.00   419.20   594.40
Page    1 CropBox:      0.00     0.00   419.20   594.40
Page    1 BleedBox:     0.00     0.00   419.20   594.40
Page    1 TrimBox:      0.00     0.00   419.20   594.40
Page    1 ArtBox:       0.00     0.00   419.20   594.40
File size:      1023501 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.5
```

output from `pdfinfo -box -f 1 -l 3 bg.pdf`:

```
Producer:       GPL Ghostscript 9.05
CreationDate:   Wed May 21 16:00:30 2014
ModDate:        Wed May 21 16:00:30 2014
Tagged:         no
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page    1 size: 419.2 x 594.4 pts
Page    1 MediaBox:     0.00     0.00   419.20   594.40
Page    1 CropBox:      0.00     0.00   419.20   594.40
Page    1 BleedBox:     0.00     0.00   419.20   594.40
Page    1 TrimBox:      0.00     0.00   419.20   594.40
Page    1 ArtBox:       0.00     0.00   419.20   594.40
File size:      145877 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.4
```

The command I'm using to overlay is: `pdftk bg.pdf stamp top.pdf output test.pdf`

As you can see from the attached test.pdf the top.pdf is cropped before being stamped onto the image. If I stamp two PDFs from the same source it works without cropping. However all the PDFs are exactly the same size! Any ideas?

http://image.secureweb.ie/pub/bg.pdf 
http://image.secureweb.ie/pub/top.pdf

Comment: http://image.secureweb.ie/pub/test.pdf

Comment: Unfortunately, `pdfinfo` does not *always* display the Crop-/Bleed-/Trim-/ArtBox values as they are specified inside the PDF file. In cases were these values do not make any sense (or are 'illegal' or are not specified at all), `pdfinfo` instead displays values which it falls back to in lieu of the nonsense values from the file (that is, it uses the same ones that are used for MediaBox).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tools you are using are not the best you could choose. They are giving you false information. I have opened your three files in iText RUPS, and this is what I see:

[image]

From left to right, we see:

- bg.pdf with a MediaBox with value [0 0 419.2 594.4] and a CropBox of [-8.665 -8.94 427.87 603.343]. This is, of course, wrong: the CropBox can't be bigger than the MediaBox.
- top.pdf with a MediaBox with value [0 0 419.200012 594.400024] and no CropBox
- test.pdf with the same values for the MediaBox and the CropBox as bg.pdf

I would fix the CropBox value before manipulating the PDFs.

Comment: Spot on Bruno.

I ended up using Podofo to remove the CropBox and it worked.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Podofo